# Why does my Datastax spark run out of memory?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, datastax, datastax-enterprise

My memory is 32GB but after 1-2 days I everytime run out of memory. I currently have around 5,200,000 rows. I have around 51GB which is a lot. My RF is 3. I have a cluster with 4 nodes: 3 Spark and 1 Solr. 1 node has 64GB and the other 2 have 32GB. I don't know how to solve this. Thanks for your replies.

This is the command I use to run the app:

```
screen -dmS spark dse spark-submit --master spark://localhost:7077 --executor-memory 2G --driver-memory 1G --total-executor-cores 6 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.4.1 --jars /root/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-1.4.1.jar  /root/pythonspark/com/spark/application.py appcationname source
```

Comment: What exactly is out of memory? I recommend you watch the spark training on DataStax academy and understand the different processes in spark. Also, always provide a full stack trace .

Comment: 1 node had 1 GB free memory left, 2 node had 6GB free memory the last one 3GB. I assumed it will crash soon so I restarted it. In the past it was also similar.

Comment: What do you mean by "memory left"

Comment: free memory the rest was used

Comment: Look up how Linux manages memory and page cache.

Comment: currently I did not set up swap on the servers. Did you mean this by your last linux remark? I am afraid that if I add this, my spark app will be slower. What do you think? thanks

Comment: My point is that Linux free has no bearing or impact of the memory availability within the JVM. Spark uses multiple jvm processes. Try figuring out which one is coming and please post the full trace.

Comment: Ok thanks. Should the system crash I will sent the full trace. Or is there another way to figure out which one it is before?

Comment: Find out if its the spark driver or executor that is oom. Maybe you need to allocate more memory to its heap.